# Typescript create object with properties with given keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is simplified case what i am struggling.

```
 const createObj = <T extends string>(keys: T[]) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
   keys.map((key) => [key, 0])
  );
 };

const result = createObj(["hi","hello","gg"] as const)
```

I hoped the result type would be `{hi: 0, hello: 0, gg: 0 }`
but the result is `any`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in this way :

```
function createObj<T extends string>(arr: T[]): Record<T, number> {
  let result = {} as Record<T, number>;

  arr.forEach((x, i) => {
    result[x] = i;
  })

  return result
}


const object = createObj(["hi","hello","gg"])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQeQEYBWAPACqJoAe2YAJgM6J1QoxgDmAfABQYooBciEgG0AugEpBAJTQQ4KGqQA0iMCAC2eNCg6IA3gChEiADZooidHRAmLAXn0BfRBgYy5C5ao1adAbgMjFz4AOmB5AFEMCAALLi4KFRhxRDtdQ2NjKxsoYQpRVMQYAONHcUCs8xAUJGzbA0dAgzkwJnIKDHUABzNC1ExsfAIuYQAiGJhRpXG0ExM4KdG2NlGJJspOnrQQoA)